# Using stax parser in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, xml-parsing, stax

I am trying to get the stax parser working inside Groovy. But I am getting the following exception.

```
Caught: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found
at com.charan.xml.parser.XmlParserDelete.run(XmlParserDelete.groovy:15)
```

Code I'm using:

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
//class XmlParserDelete {
//
//}

XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to statements element

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
while(xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), result);
    Node domNode = result.getNode();
}
```

Tried using **stax-1.2.0.jar** as the dependency. But getting the following error.

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
at com.charan.xml.parser.XmlParserDelete.run(XmlParserDelete.groovy:15)
```

Has anyone tried using Stax with Groovy ? Please help me solve this.

Comment: Do you want to apply xslt sheet on an xml document?

Comment: No, I am trying to create a utility to parse a very large document. Given a path, I want to extract out the DOM for that specific path in the document. But I have build all that in Java. I wanted to use that utility with groovy, so that I can do some quick analysis on the data. Its not working because the stax parsing itself is failing in groovy.

Comment: If you need to read xml in groovy, that is even simple. You should be able find groovy samples in stackoverflow or internet.

Comment: I am aware of that. But all that won't work for a very large XML file. We have to use a SAX or STAX parser. I am not able to make that work in groovy.